# What's the __repr__ equivalence in ruby?

Tags: python, ruby

The `__repr__` function of python is fancy as it is called when print OBJECT is used automatically.

Is there a ruby equivalence for it? I thought it was to_s, but, I had p OBJECT doesn't seem to call the to_s method.

### Added

I got something wrong, p OBJECT seems to call to_s method as follows. 
I got some hints from my the answers to my other question. - [Ruby's to_s method question (from Axe book 2nd edition)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625093/rubys-to-s-method-question-from-axe-book-2nd-edition)

```
# Sample code from Programing Ruby, page 24
class Song
  def to_s
    "Song"
  end
end

class Songson < Song
  def to_s
    super + "<Songson>"
  end
end

song = Songson.new()
p song
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
  obj.inspect => string
```

Returns a string containing a human-readable representation of `obj`. **If not overridden, uses the `to_s` method to generate the string.**

```
   [ 1, 2, 3..4, 'five' ].inspect   #=> "[1, 2, 3..4, \"five\"]"
   Time.new.inspect                 #=> "Wed Apr 09 08:54:39 CDT 2003"
```

```
 obj.to_s => string
```

Returns a string representing `obj`. The default `to_s` prints the object‘s class and an encoding of the object id. As a special case, the top-level object that is the initial execution context of Ruby programs returns ``main.’‘

[source](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000359)

Comment: @TheMachineCharmer : Could you check my other question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625667/why-ruby-has-to-s-and-inspect ? <<If not overridden, uses the to_s method to generate the string.>> <-- doesn't seem to wrok.

Comment: Inspect - If not overridden, uses the to_s method to generate the string.---Completely true.
@prosseek - Try writing a simple class and do to_s and inspect on its instance - both will return the same.
inspect has been overridden on predefined classes like Array,Hash ... that's why they print differently.

Answer (score 3):

p object uses #inspect.