# Why do this Ruby object have both to_s and inspect methods that appear to do the same thing?

Tags: ruby, object, printing

Why do this Ruby object both a `to_s` and `inspect` methods that appear to do the same thing?

The `p` method calls `inspect` and puts/print calls `to_s` for representing the object.

If I run

```
class Graph
  def initialize
    @nodeArray = Array.new
    @wireArray = Array.new
  end
  def to_s # called with print / puts
    "Graph : #{@nodeArray.size}"
  end
  def inspect # called with p
    "G"
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  gr = Graph.new
  p gr
  print gr
  puts gr
end
```

I get

```
G
Graph : 0
Graph : 0
```

- Then, why does Ruby have two functions do the same thing? What is the difference between `to_s` and `inspect`?
- And what's the difference between `puts`, `print`, and `p`?

If I comment out the `to_s` or `inspect` function, I get as follows.

```
#<Graph:0x100124b88>
#<Graph:0x100124b88>
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`inspect` is used more for debugging and `to_s` for end-user or display purposes.

For example, `[1,2,3].to_s` and `[1,2,3].inspect` produce different output.

Comment: I am probably doing something wrong, but to me in IRB the outputs were the same: `"[1, 2, 3]"`. On the other hand, `nil.to_s` and `nil.inspect` produced `""` and `"nil"` respectively.

Comment: same here, to_s and inspect return same output (as of March 2013)

Comment: `[1,2,3].to_s => "123"`; `[1,2,3].inspect => "[1, 2, 3]"`. `"#{...}"` uses the former; `p ...` uses the latter.

Comment: Using ruby 1.8.7 I get `[1,2,3].to_s => "123"`. With ruby 2.0.0 I get `[1,2,3].to_s => "[1, 2, 3]"`. So the given example is either true or not true depending on what version you are talking about.

Comment: According to release docs, starting in 2.0.0 "Object#inspect does always return a string like #<ClassName:0x…> instead of delegating to #to_s. [#2152]", so the difference between to_s and inspect is probably clearer in IRB once you upgrade. See: http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/02/24/ruby-2-0-0-p0-is-released/

Comment: Weird, for Regexp on 2.1.1 it feels like the contrary: `/a/.inspect` gives `/a/` which is human readable, but `/a/.to_s` gives `(?-mix:a)`.

Comment: Ruby 1.9 changed `Array#to_s` to be `Array#inspect`.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/3960392/

Comment: As of today, version 2.6.3, I get the same output for both.

Answer (score 34):

`inspect` is a method that, by default, tells you the class name, the instance's `object_id`, and lists off the instance's instance variables.

`print` and `puts` are used, as you already know, to put the value of the object's `to_s` method to `STDOUT`.  As indicated by Ruby's documentation, [`Object#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000359) returns a string representing the object -- used for end-user readability.

`print` and `puts` are identical to each other except for `puts` automatically appends a newline, while `print` does not.

Comment: `Time.new.inspect` isn't showing the `class` name and `object_id`, it rather prints `"2016-11-10 13:05:45 +0530"` (Time in `string`)

Answer (score 14):

To compare with Python, `to_s` is like `__str__` and `inspect` is like `__repr__`. `to_s` gives you a string, whereas `inspect` gives you the string representation of the object. You can use the latter to construct an object if you wish.

Comment: But in Python `eval(repr(z)) == z` should be True: how do you achieve this in Ruby?

Comment: `eval(repr(z)) == z` is a myth. It's very rarely a useful thing to do, and has lots of potential problems. This article is a good start: http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com.au/2013/11/repr-eval-bad-idea.html

Comment: Alex Martelli expresses the same sentiment here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1436756/665488. It's just too hard to keep your `__repr__`s working like that, for very little real practical advantage.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone arriving here after starting out with [Ruby Koans](http://rubykoans.com/), a simple example of where `to_s` and `inspect` differ in output is this:

```
nil.to_s     # will yield an empty string, ie ""
nil.inspect  # will yield the string "nil"
```

Answer (score 5):

Further, there is a `to_str` method on certain objects, which you would call when you need a String-like object, and not just a string representation. (Try in IRB: `[1,2,3].to_str` and it will fail, yet `[1,2,3].to_s` will not.) I feel I should mention this because I've been bitten by it before :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean with a string-like object, but as far as I understood, `to_s` is meant for string representation and as such is used on interpolation, whereas `to_str` is meant for implicit conversions such as type coersion.

Answer (score 3):

`puts` generally prints the result of applying `to_s` on an object, while `p` prints the result of `inspect`ing the object.

There is a subtle difference between `inspect` and `to_s`:

- `inspect`, when applied on an object, returns the object hex code
  along with the instance variable
- `to_s`, when applied on an object,returns only the object hex code

  ```
  class Item
   def initialize(abc)
    @abc=abc
   end
  end

  x= Item.new(22)

  puts x         #prints object x hex code  
  puts x.inspect #prints object x hex code WITH INSTANCE VARIABLE @abc 
  puts x.to_s    #prints object x hex code

  p x            #prints object x hex code WITH INSTANCE VARIABLE @abc
  p x.inspect    #prints object x hex code WITH INSTANCE VARIABLE @abc
  p x.to_s       #prints object x hex code
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Answer from Chris Pine's Learn To Program book

"The inspect method is a lot like to_s, except that the string it returns tries to show you the ruby code for building the object you passed it."

Thus the inspect method will return an array for example like this...

```
[25, 16, 9, 4, 1, 0]
```

Where as puts / to_s will return

```
25
16
9
4
1
0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
2.0.0p195 :075 > puts (1..5).to_a                  # Put an array as a string.
1
2
3
4
5
=> nil 
2.0.0p195 :076 > puts (1..5).to_a.inspect          # Put a literal array.
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
=> nil 
2.0.0p195 :077 > puts :name, :name.inspect
name
:name
=> nil 
2.0.0p195 :078 > puts "It worked!", "It worked!".inspect    
It worked! 
"It worked!"
=> nil 
2.0.0p195 :079 > p :name                           # Same as 'puts :name.inspect'
:name
=> :name
```

From the [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-flavored-ruby#top)

Answer (score 0):

Refer following link for more information and examples explaining difference between "to_s" and "inspect" as well as difference between "puts" and "p".
https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/45-more-classes/lessons/108-displaying-objects