# Ruby 1.9 Array.to_s behaves differently?

Tags: ruby, string, ruby-1.9

i wrote a quick little application that takes a base file of code with some keywords, a file of replacements for the keywords, and outputs a new file with the keywords replaced.

When i was using Ruby 1.8, my outputs would look fine. Now when using Ruby 1.9, my replaced code has the newline characters in it instead of line feeds.

For example, i see something like:

```
["\r\nDim RunningNormal_1 As Boolean", "\r\nDim RunningNormal_2 As Boolean", "\r\nDim RunningNormal_3 As Boolean"]
```

instead of:

```
Dim RunningNormal_1 As Boolean
Dim RunningNormal_2 As Boolean
Dim RunningNormal_3 As Boolean
```

i use a hash of replacements {"KEYWORD"=>["1","2","3"]} and an array of the replaced lines.

i use this block to finish the replacement:

```
resultingLibs.each do |x|
  libraryString.sub!(/(<REPEAT>(.*?)<\/REPEAT>)/im) do |match|
    x.each do |individual|
      individual.to_s 
    end
  end
end
#for each resulting group of the repeatable pattern,
#  
#Write out the resulting libs to a combined string
```

My hunch is that i'm printing out the array instead of the strings within the array. Any suggestions on a fix. When i debug and print my replaced string using puts, the output looks correct. When i use the to_s method (which is how my app writes the output to the output file), my output looks wrong.

A fix would be nice, but what i really want to know is what changed between Ruby 1.8 and 1.9 that causes this behavior. Has the to_s method changed somehow in Ruby 1.9?

*i'm inexperienced in Ruby

Comment: i added the source code that i hope is relevant.

Comment: +1. I've been using Ruby 1.8 and 1.9 a fair bit, but never knew about this difference!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, you're calling `to_s` on an array of strings. In 1.8 that is equivalent to calling `join`, in 1.9 it is equivalent to calling `inspect`.

To get the behavior you want in both 1.8 and 1.9, call `join` instead of `to_s`.

Comment: When is `inspect` useful?

Comment: @chongman You mean for arrays over `to_s`? It would be useful in case the thing you're trying to inspect happens not to be an array after all. Also using `p`/`inspect` to inspect arrays is just clearer and more consistent since that's what you use to inspect other values.

Comment: Thanks. I realize my confusion was a 1.8.6(?) vs 1.9 issue. A tutorial showed ' "The Cat In Hat".to_a '  and then I assumed 'to_s' should return the original string, which I believe it does in 1.8.6. In 1.9, to_a is eliminated as a method for strings.

'split(" ")' and 'join' are the inverses.

Answer (score 3):

Please see [here](http://eigenclass.org/hiki.rb?Changes+in+Ruby+1.9#l11), under `Array`

```
Array#to_s is equivalent to Array#inspect

[1,2,3,4].to_s                                    # => "[1, 2, 3, 4]"

instead of

RUBY_VERSION                                      # => "1.8.5"
[1,2,3,4].to_s                                    # => "1234"
```