# Why does Array.to_s return brackets?

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays, html-parsing

For an array, when I type:

```
puts array[0]

==> text
```

Yet when I type

```
puts array[0].to_s

==> ["text"]
```

Why the brackets and quotes? What am I missing?

ADDENDUM: my code looks like this

```
page = open(url)  {|f| f.read }
page_array = page.scan(/regex/) #pulls partial urls into an array
partial_url = page_array[0].to_s
full_url = base_url + partial_url #adds each partial url to a consistent base_url
puts full_url
```

what I'm getting looks like:

```
http://www.stackoverflow/["questions"]
```

Comment: What's in your `array`? And which Ruby version are you talking about (there's a difference here between 1.8 and 1.9)

Comment: Show us definition of your array

Comment: Put that in your question; that's illegible.

Comment: Try `p array` and I think you'll get `[["text"]]` output. I'm just guessing.

Comment: @Iain but what does that get me? How do I get just the text, without the quotes and brackets?

Comment: probably [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960392/ruby-1-9-array-to-s-behaves-differently) will answer your question.

Comment: And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/38765) will question your question.

Answer (score 21):

This print the array as is without brackets

```
array.join(", ")
```

Answer (score 12):

to_s is just an alias to inspect for the Array class.

Not that this means a lot other than instead of expecting array.to_s to return a string it's actually returning array.inspect which, based on the name of the method, isn't really what you are looking for.

If you want just the "guts" try:

```
page_array.join
```

If there are multiple elements to the array:

```
page_array.join(" ")
```

This will make:

```
page_array = ["test","this","function"]
```

return:

```
"test this function"
```

What "to_s" on an Array returns, depends on the version of Ruby you are using as mentioned above.  1.9.X returns:

```
"[\"test\"]"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to show us the regex to really fix this properly, but this will do it:

Replace this

```
partial_url = page_array[0].to_s
```

with this

```
partial_url = page_array[0][0]
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it. But you're right, it was a regex issue.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't necessarily fix **why** you are getting a doubled-up array, but you can flatten it and then call the first element like this.

```
page_array = page.scan(/regex/).flatten
```

Flattening takes out stacked arrays and creates one level, so if you had `[1,2,[3,[4,5,6]]]` and called flatten on it, you would get `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

It is also more robust than doing `array[0][0]`, because, if you had more than two arrays nested in the first element, you would run into the same issue.

Iain is correct though, without seeing the regex, we can't suss out the root cause.