# can't convert Array into String - add <ul> tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following controller code:

```
class NodesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @nodes = Node.com_name_scope("27").find(:all, :conditions => ['COMPONENT_NAME LIKE ?', "#{params[:search]}%"])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render :js => @nodes.map { |node|  "<li>#{node.COMPONENT_NAME}</li>"}}
    end
end
```

When I do:

```
http://localhost/myproject/nodes.js
```

I get the following list:

```
<li>Value A</li>
<li>Value B</li>
<li>Value C</li>
<li>Value D</li>
```

I would like to insert a `<ul>` tag at the start and end of the list so that it look as follows:

```
<ul>
<li>Value A</li>
<li>Value B</li>
<li>Value C</li>
<li>Value D</li>
</ul>
```

But when I do:

```
format.js {render :js => "ul" + @nodes.map { |node|  "<li>#{node.COMPONENT_NAME}</li>"}+ "</ul>" }
```

It is giving me the following error message:

```
 TypeError in NodesController#index

can't convert Array into String
```

My question is how do I include the `<ul>` tag in front and at the end of the list.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@nodes.map { |node|  "<li>#{node.COMPONENT_NAME}</li>"}
```

returns an array of strings, you need to join them in some way before merging them with the string.

```
format.js { render :js => "<ul>#{@nodes.map { |node|  "<li>#{node.COMPONENT_NAME}</li>"}.join}</ul>" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to convert the array `@nodes.map { }` to a string:

```
format.js { render :js => "<ul>" + (@nodes.map { |node|  "<li>#{node.COMPONENT_NAME}</li>"}).to_s + "</ul>" }
```

Comment: `Array#to_s` has inconsistent behavior depending on the Ruby version. You should use `Array#join`

Comment: @SimoneCarletti: Thanks for this hint. I tested it on an older machine with ruby 1.8.4, where it worked as expected. What would be the behavior in other versions?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960392/ruby-1-9-array-to-s-behaves-differently

Answer (score 1):

The following example should work:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js do
    mapped = @nodes.map { |node|  "<li>#{node.COMPONENT_NAME}</li>"}
    mapped.unshift "<ul>"
    mapped.push "</ul>"

    render :js => mapped
  end
end
```

But note, your code looks still strange.
You respond to your :js with a html-fragment?