# Difference in `Array#to_s` in Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby 1.9 Array.to_s behaves differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960392/ruby-1-9-array-to-s-behaves-differently)

I wonder if anyone can tell me what changed between Ruby 1.8.7 and Ruby 1.9.3. I have an example listed below that behaves totally different in the 2 versions but according to the Ruby docs it doesn't appear anything changed between these versions.

Ruby 1.8

```
number = '123-45-6789' 
# => "123-45-6789"
number.scan(/[0-9]/)
# => ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
number.scan(/[0-9]/).to_s
# => "123456789"
```

Ruby 1.9

```
number = '123-45-6789'
# => "123-45-6789" 
number.scan(/[0-9]/)
# => ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]    
number.scan(/[0-9]/).to_s
# => "[\"1\", \"2\", \"3\", \"4\", \"5\", \"6\", \"7\", \"8\", \"9\"]"
```

Not really looking for a different way to do this just curious as to what changed between the two versions.

Comment: When a new learner doesn't jump to the same conclusion as you, it hurts our community when you reward that person being intellectually curious with an insult. Rememeber: Matz Is Nice An So We Are Nice (MINASWAN)

Comment: @sawa Im pretty new to Ruby thus I came here to ask for help. Thanks for going out of your way to make me feel as dumb as possible with your condescending reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what is actually in Ruby source code:

1.8.7:

```
rb_ary_to_s(ary)
    VALUE ary;
{
    if (RARRAY(ary)->len == 0) return rb_str_new(0, 0);
    return rb_ary_join(ary, rb_output_fs);
}
```

In other words, in 1.8.7, `to_s` calls `join`.

1.9.3:

```
rb_ary_inspect(VALUE ary)
{
    if (RARRAY_LEN(ary) == 0) return rb_usascii_str_new2("[]");
    return rb_exec_recursive(inspect_ary, ary, 0);
}

VALUE
rb_ary_to_s(VALUE ary)
{
    return rb_ary_inspect(ary);
}
```

In other words, in 1.9.3, `to_s` delegates to `inspect`.

Note: in future, if you're wondering about a difference you're observing between two versions, you can try taking a look at source code. Easy to pull down from here: https://github.com/ruby/ruby

Not everything is going to be easy to find in there of course, but if you search around for a bit you can often find good leads.  In this case, `array.c` has what you're looking for.

Then you can switch back and forth between versions by issuing `git checkout ruby_1_8_7` and `git checkout ruby_1_9_3`.

Comment: ah! I can see why the `1.8` implementation was faster from my microbenchmark. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: github's blame feature leads me to the [commit](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/d1cb9e75d054d06f0a80aeb112b894e82952c6d0), and the comment there leads me to [the discussion](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ja&u=http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-dev/29520&prev=search) but that leaves me little the wiser as to the reason.

Answer (score 2):

The `to_s` has been changed to actually do what converting an object to a string should do.

Consider the 1.8 implementation...

1. When you send to `to_s` method to the array object, it literally does `array_object.join('').to_s`. This IMHO does too much.
2. This implementation also misrepresents the array object. The `to_s` method mainly goes hand-in-hand with the `inspect` method (_correct me if I'm wrong because I am working off my head here). And if you should look at the output of the `to_s` method here, you cannot tell if the object is of the `Array`, `String` or `Fixnum` class.

Enter 1.9 implementation...

1. The structure of the output clearly shows the object is an array.

That been said, I think this was a UX design decision from the Ruby team ...because the `to_s` in 1.8 is considerably faster!

Consider this microbenchmark...

```
OS_X_Terminal $> time ruby -e "(1..1000000).to_a.map(&:to_s).to_s"

| Ruby Version | average runtime |
|    1.9.3     |      1.678      |
|    1.9.2     |      1.817      |
|    1.8.7     |      1.106      |
```

This is all I have so far. Comments are always welcome (:

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ruby just got smarter about what `.to_s` does.  It used to be dumb and for some reason list all entries in the array side by side.  In ruby 1.9 it takes the array and literally turns it in to a string.  That is a smarter way of handling `.to_s`.