# Inconsistent printing with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to print a ruby hash:

```
opts = {
  'one' => '1',
  'two' => '1',
  'three' => '0'
}
```

I want the output to be

```
one=1
two=1
three=0
```

This works fine with this code on one machine which runs ruby 1.8.7

```
print opts.map{|k,v| k + '=' + v + "\n"}.to_s
```

But on a different machine which runs ruby 1.9, it prints

```
["one=1\n", "two=1\n", "three=0\n"]
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
print opts.map{|k,v| k + '=' + v + "\n"}.join
```

The explanation is easy: With ruby 1.9 [`Array.to_s` changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960392/ruby-1-9-array-to-s-behaves-differently) its behaviour.

An alternative:

```
puts opts.map{|k,v| k + '=' + v }.join("\n")
```

or

```
puts opts.map{|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}" }.join("\n")
```

I would prefer:

```
opts.each{|k,v| puts "#{k}=#{v}" }
```

And another version, but with another look:

```
opts.each{|k,v| puts "%-10s= %s" % [k,v]}
```

The result is:

```
one       = 1
two       = 1
three     = 0
```

(But the keys should be not longer then the length in `%-10s`.)

Comment: Nice and detailed answer!

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the second alternative.

Answer (score 4):

It's working as expected. Give this a try:

```
a={:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3}
a.each {|k,v| puts "#{k}=>#{v}" }
```

Comment: You forgot the `newline` :)

Comment: @alfasin nope, hi did not ;)

Comment: You got +1 from me then :)))

Comment: @alfasin The `puts` add its own newline. But there is an additional `>` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
res = ""
opts.map{|k,v| res += k + '=' + v + "\n"}
puts res
```

Comment: It's really redundant to create a local variable for just printing Hash's content.

Comment: @DavidUnric right, there's a waste of two bytes on the stack... ;)

Comment: @alfasin Too optimistic etsimate for a full String class instance.

Comment: @DavidUnric touche! :)

Comment: @alfasin ```Memory.analyze("one=1\ntwo=2\nthree=3\n")```  #<struct Memory::MemoryInfo roots=["one=1\ntwo=2\nthree=3\n"], objects=1, **bytes=24**, loops=0>

Comment: @DavidUnric well, that's still not much, is it ? :)))