# How do I write an attachment ZIP to file with Ruby's File.new?

Tags: ruby, unzip

I am connecting to a IMAP server and downloading a message with a ZIP attachment. I am running my script on my local machine, and on a remote machine. I am able to save the file correctly on both machines, but for some reason I am getting errors when unzipping on the remote machine.

My ruby code that saves the zip attachment:

```
attachment = imap.fetch(message_id, "BODY[2]")[0].attr["BODY[2]"]
save_path = "#{save_path_base}/#{fname}"
File.new(save_path, "wb+").write(attachment.unpack("m"))
```

On my local machine (OS X) running `unzip file.zip` on the file works perfectly, but on the remote machine (CentOS) the same command produces an error:

*End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.*

What could be causing the file to be saved correctly on my local machine and corruptedly on the remote machine? Or is my local unzip ignoring errors? On both machines `unzip` points to `/usr/bin/unzip`.

**EDIT:**

On my local machine, `file file.zip` gives me *Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract.* My local Ruby version is `ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358)`

On my remote server the command returns *ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators.* My remote Ruby version is `ruby 2.0.0p647 (2015-08-18)`

How do I ensure the file is recognized as a ZIP on the remote machine?

**EDIT: Solution added below as an answer**

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer to your own question and then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was, of course, figuring out what changed between Ruby versions. [In this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960392/ruby-1-9-array-to-s-behaves-differently) it is pointed out, that:

> In 1.8 that is equivalent to calling `join`, in 1.9 it is equivalent to calling `inspect`. To get the behavior you want in both 1.8 and 1.9, call `join` instead of `to_s`.

So the solution was to change the line to

```
File.new(save_path, "wb+").write(attachment.unpack("m").join)
```

Because by default `write` calls `to_s` if something besides a string is supplied.