# Difference between x.inspect and x.to_s in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do this Ruby object have two to_s and inspect methods that do the same thing? Or, so it seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625667/why-do-this-ruby-object-have-two-to-s-and-inspect-methods-that-do-the-same-thing)

In Ruby:
If x is some variable, 
is there a difference between using x.inspect and using x.to_s? 
What is the difference between the 2 methods?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are usually but not always the same.  According to [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-inspect) for `Object.inspect()`:

> If not overridden, uses the to_s method to generate the string.

So by default, they return the same thing because `inspect()` calls `to_s()`.  Sometimes, however, it makes sense to override `to_s()` to do one thing, but when inspecting an object from irb, you want to see more details.  So they can be set up to do different things.

Comment: This is no longer the case, as of ruby 2.1.1 (at least, haven't checked backwards) `inspect` does not call `to_s` by default. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-inspect

Comment: @PauloCasaretto The 2.1.1 source code shows that for non-compound objects that don't override `inspect()`, Ruby will call `rb_any_to_s` on the object.  So the documentation is worded differently, and the C implementation has been modified, but the behavior remains the same as I've described here.  (For compound objects, `inspect()` is called until recursing to an object with an overridden `inspect()` or a non-compound object, just as before.)